# How to restore the Whatsapp Messenger icon? Not the app, just the icon

Tags: whatsapp-messenger

Since quite some time now, the Whatsapp Messenger icon is not the proper icon, but the Android green trashcan icon. The app in itself is working properly, it just looks funny on the home screen.

Reinstalling is an obvious solution, but I would loose my chat history. Wouldn't I?

CAT B15Q, Android 4.4.2 (I know, ancient).

Comment: If you backup your chat history first, you can then uninstall/reinstall and restore your chat history.

Comment: can you please check this: clear cache and data of your launcher from settings-> appliactions-> your stock launcher-> storage. Please note that it will reset your home screen arrangement to default. Or else you can try with another launcher (nova launcher ). by using nova launcher you can customize many things especially icons.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After many automatic updates, one of the most recent ones spontaneously restored the app icon!

And after a few more updates, the proper icon was once again replaced by the Android green trashcan icon.

Answer (score 0):

On my phone, you can bin the faulty WhatsApp icon and then reselect it from the installed apps list with the right icon.